# what does the "next" field do in java.lang.ref.Reference

Tags: java, reference

According to the comment：

```
 * With this scheme the collector need only examine the next field in order
 * to determine whether a Reference instance requires special treatment: If
 * the next field is null then the instance is active; if it is non-null,
 * then the collector should treat the instance normally.
```

What does exactly **special treatment** and **treat the instance normally** mean?

Comment: [java.lang.ref.Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ref/Reference.html) doesn't appear to have such field. Can you clarify?

Comment: @MargaretBloom It seems to be a package-private field in the source code.

Comment: @MargaretBloom，http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/ref/Reference.java#Reference